# jquery: assigning div to object variable for caching

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that works inside a function:

```
$('#MyPanel').stop().animate({ top: PanelTop }, 300);
```

However, I'd like to assign the div to an object so that jquery doesn't have to reevaluate the reference every time.

I have a global variable and then I want to work with it in my function like this:

```
var ThePanel = $('#MyPanel');

ThePanel.stop().animate({ top: PanelTop }, 300);
```

Nothing happens. Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Every little computer cycle helps, but you don't have to worry too much about the cost of ID selectors; it is very efficient since it uses document.getElementById() http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: @rkw caching selectors (and using `this` where appropriate) provides a _significant_ performance increase. See: http://jsperf.com/thisnthat/2

Comment: @melee ah, cool site.  I updated the test to include selector by id.  There is a difference between selector by ID vs selector by class. http://jsperf.com/thisnthat/3

Comment: @rkw durf, good point. The site was down when I pasted it so I missed that, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to declare the global variable as null and then assign the div to the object variable in the document.ready function instead of in the global declaration section.

```
<script>

  var ThePanel = null;

  $(document).ready(function () {

    ThePanel = $('#MyPanel');

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to "cache" an object is correct. I suspect something else is going on... are you sure the first piece of code works but the second one doesn't?

I would use FireBug or the built in web debugging tools (like in Chrome) to put a stop on that line and see if ThePanel is null..

Comment: I got it: in the global declaration you set the variable to null and you put the line to assign the variable in the document.ready function !!

Comment: @frenchie:  For the benefit of future readers, you should post your solution (along with relevant code) as a new answer and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(ThePanel).stop...` and you're away. As far as I know this will still give you the required performance gain